# How to show function signature/jsdoc of imports in VScode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

When hovering a method in vscode, it shows the signature and jsdoc of the method.

However when hovering a function like `setState` from react, it currently shows a typescript signature (`~/Library/Caches/typescript/3.5/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts`)

I am not using typescript and just want to see the signature and doc of the imported file from `node_modules`. I tried different settings and googled for solutions, but could not find anything helpful.

**Is there a way to show the original signature/jsdoc from the import, rather than the typescript signature/jsdoc?**

Comment: Do you have @types/react in your node_modules?

Comment: no, I do not. maybe it is a caching problem.

Comment: I'd suggest to add it as a dependency (or devdependency) to try it out

Comment: it works in the sense, that it now shows the jsdoc from node_modules, but it shows the jsdoc of the typescript function. what I want is the jsdoc of the imported class/function.

Comment: I believe there are language providers for each module. On hover you'd see results from corresponding language provider automatically. I'm not sure but I'd guess typescript definitions has precedence over jsdoc. But you can try with some module who has both definitions. Maybe they are merged? But if you check react in node_modules, there is no jsdoc. Everything is written in @types package, which makes more sense anyways

Comment: I just checked the documentation above setState in node_modules/react/dist/react which is much more helpful than just the type definitions.

Comment: Oh, I guess different package managers download dependencies differently. In my node_modules/react, I only have cjs and umd folders. No dist, no jsdoc. But in node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts I have couple of sentences for two useState functions (one overloaded version)